# linux mint I press "Standby mode" the PC goes into it for a second and immediately turns on itself. How to fix it? linuxmint-21.2-cinnamon-64bit 5.15

Tags: linux-mint, suspend

try commant to : pm-suspend,use autologin,
cat /proc/swaps /swapfile

windwos sleep mode work perefect
video drivers installed

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
GP12      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
GP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:08.1
XHC0      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:07:00.3
GP30      S4    *disabled
GP31      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S3    *disabled
PS2M      S3    *disabled
GPP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.1
GPP8      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:03.1
PTXH      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:02:00.0
PT20      S4    *disabled
PT23      S4    *disabled
PT24      S4    *disabled
PT26      S4    *disabled
PT27      S4    *disabled
PT28      S4    *disabled
PT29      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:03:09.0
```

i try

```
echo XHC0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo USB0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo USB2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup \
echo PEG0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```